# Would vs Would have

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> He threw away all pictures that **would** remind him of his girlfriend.
>
> He threw away all pictures that **would have** reminded him of his girlfriend.

What is the difference between those sentences?

---

Edit: I think the first suggests that the pictures still remind him of his girlfriend if (he see them today or in future) and the second suggests that the pictures would have reminded him of his girlfriend in the past ( if he had kept them). *- from comments*

Comment: What do you think is the difference? What does your research say?

Comment: It's the subtle distinction between **the pictures that would remind him when he saw them** and **the pictures that would have reminded him if he had kept them**.

Comment: AIQ , I think the first suggests that the pictures still remind him of his girlfriend if (he see them today or in future) and the second suggests that the pictures  would have remind him of his girlfriend in the past ( if he had kept them)

Comment: @thedev09 No, the second is the conditional so that "He" didn't look at all pictures and threw all of them away. ( which "could have" reminded him of his girlfriend )

Comment: And the first ?

Comment: The first is the simple statement so we don't know if "he" saw the pictures with his eyes before throwing them away, We can not know if he saw or didn't by only this context.